# Round negative numbers up to zero

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a SQL query that returns the number of years an employee has been employed over the age of 41 based on their date of birth and start date. But obviously some employees are under 41. For these I would like to return a zero but my current attempt returns negatives.

How can I "round up" the negatives to zero?

```
select EmployeeNo, EmployeeFName, EmployeeLName,
 DATEDIFF(hour,DateOfBirth,GETDATE())/8766 AS Age, 
 DATEDIFF(hour,StartDate,GETDATE())/8766 AS LengthOfService, 
 DATEDIFF(hour,DateOfBirth,GETDATE())/8766 - 41 AS YearsOver41
from Employees
```

Comment: have you tried a case statement?  CASE DATEDIFF(hour,DateOfBirth,GETDATE())/8766 - 41  < 0  THEN 0 ELSE DATEDIFF(hour,DateOfBirth,GETDATE())/8766 - 41  END YearsOver41

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select EmployeeNo, EmployeeFName, EmployeeLName,
   DATEDIFF(hour,DateOfBirth,GETDATE())/8766 AS Age, 
   DATEDIFF(hour,StartDate,GETDATE())/8766 AS LengthOfService, 

   CASE 
       WHEN DATEDIFF(hour,DateOfBirth,GETDATE())/8766 - 41) < 0 THEN 0
       ELSE DATEDIFF(hour,DateOfBirth,GETDATE())/8766 - 41 
   END AS YearsOver41

from Employees
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CASE WHEN X < 0 THEN 0 ELSE X END
```

where X is a numeric column or expression that may be negative.